# How to use radio buttons in a quiz using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I am new to coding and working on a quiz app which I am stuck on. I changed the HTML below from ul/li to input since it is a requirement to use radio buttons. Since I changed that part, I am not sure what I did wrong in JS as the answers are not corresponding to the radio buttons.

```
<div class="quiz">
      <h2>Question</h2>
      <div class="answerChoices"></div>
      <form name=radioAnswers">
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0"><label id="label0"></label></input><br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0"><label id="label1"></label></input><br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0"><label id="label3"></label></input><br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0"><label id="label4"></label></input><br>
        </form>
```

Here is the JS. I replaced all the ul's and li's with either input/radio/label or even form in the functions. The radio buttons are above the answer choices and do not work. What would I reference in the HTML to use in JS?

```
let score = 0;
let currentQuestion = 0;
let questions = [
  {
    title: "Who is Darth Vader's son?",
    answers: ["Yoda", "Luke", "Han Solo", "R2D2"],
    correct: 1,
  },
  {
    title: "What is the name of Han Solo's ship?",
    answers: ["X-wing", "Star Cruiser", "Death Star", "Millenium Falcon"],
    correct: 3,
  },
  {
    title: "How old was Yoda when he died",
    answers: [2000, 500, 900, 1000],
    correct: 2,
  },
  {
    title: "What planet did Luke Skywalker grow up on?",
    answers: ["Tatooine", "Earth", "Hoth", "Alderaan"],
    correct: 0,
  },
  {
    title: "What is the Jedi's weapon of choice?",
    answers: ["Sword", "Plasma Rifle", "Lightsaber", "Axe"],
    correct: 2,
  },
];

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".start a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".start").hide();
    $(".quiz").show();
    showQuestion(0);
  });
  $(".quiz form").on("click", "answerChoices", function () {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });

  $(".submitAnswer").click(checkAnswer);
  $(".nextQuestion").click(nextQuestion);
  $(".restart-quiz").click(restartQuiz);
});

function showQuestion(current) {
  $(".nextQuestion").hide();
  let question = questions[current];
  $(".quiz h2").text(question.title);
  $(".quiz .answerChoices").html("");
  for (let i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
    $(".quiz form").append(`<label id='${i}'>${question.answers[i]}</label>`);
  }
}

function nextQuestion(e) {
  $(".submission").hide();
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(currentQuestion);
  if (currentQuestion < questions.length - 1) {
    currentQuestion += 1;
    showQuestion(currentQuestion);
  } else {
    console.log("results");
    showResults();
  }
}

function checkAnswer(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (!$(".selected").length) {
    return alert("Please select an answer");
  }
  $(".nextQuestion").show();
  const selected = $(".selected").text();
  const correctIdx = questions[currentQuestion].correct;
  const correct = questions[currentQuestion].answers[correctIdx];

  if ($(".selected").attr("id") == correctIdx) {
    score++;
  }

  $(".submission").show();
  $(".your-answer").text(selected);
  $(".correct-answer").text(correct);
}

function showResults() {
  $(".quiz").hide();
  $(".summary").show();
  $(".summary p").text(
    `Congrats you scored ${score} out of ${questions.length} correct!`
  );
}

function restartQuiz(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  score = 0;
  currentQuestion = 0;
  $(".quiz").show();
  $(".summary").hide();
  showQuestion(currentQuestion);
}
```

Comment: When you add the labels, you don't have a `for` attribute. Labels need a `for` attribute, which is the id of the input it is for. For example: `<input type="checkbox" id="cat">  <label for="cat">I am a cat</label>`.

Answer (score 0):

Add back the start button to trigger question generation and make some changes of js code. please take a look at the comment I marked below. Not sure if this helps.

```js
let score = 0;
let currentQuestion = 0;
let questions = [{
    title: "Who is Darth Vader's son?",
    answers: ["Yoda", "Luke", "Han Solo", "R2D2"],
    correct: 1,
  },
  {
    title: "What is the name of Han Solo's ship?",
    answers: ["X-wing", "Star Cruiser", "Death Star", "Millenium Falcon"],
    correct: 3,
  },
  {
    title: "How old was Yoda when he died",
    answers: [2000, 500, 900, 1000],
    correct: 2,
  },
  {
    title: "What planet did Luke Skywalker grow up on?",
    answers: ["Tatooine", "Earth", "Hoth", "Alderaan"],
    correct: 0,
  },
  {
    title: "What is the Jedi's weapon of choice?",
    answers: ["Sword", "Plasma Rifle", "Lightsaber", "Axe"],
    correct: 2,
  },
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".start a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".start").hide();
    $(".quiz").show();
    showQuestion(0);
  });
  $(".quiz form").on("click", "answerChoices", function() {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });

  $(".submitAnswer").click(checkAnswer);
  $(".nextQuestion").click(nextQuestion);
  $(".restart-quiz").click(restartQuiz);
});

function showQuestion(current) {
  $(".nextQuestion").hide();
  let question = questions[current];
  $(".quiz h2").text(question.title);
  $(".quiz form").html(""); // change it to form instead of .answerChoices
  for (let i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
    $(".quiz form").append(`<label id='${i}'><input type="radio" name="choice" value="0"> ${question.answers[i]}</label>`); // add radui button input as well
  }
}

function nextQuestion(e) {
  $(".submission").hide();
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(currentQuestion);
  if (currentQuestion < questions.length - 1) {
    currentQuestion += 1;
    showQuestion(currentQuestion);
  } else {
    console.log("results");
    showResults();
  }
}

function checkAnswer(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (!$(".selected").length) {
    return alert("Please select an answer");
  }
  $(".nextQuestion").show();
  const selected = $(".selected").text();
  const correctIdx = questions[currentQuestion].correct;
  const correct = questions[currentQuestion].answers[correctIdx];

  if ($(".selected").attr("id") == correctIdx) {
    score++;
  }

  $(".submission").show();
  $(".your-answer").text(selected);
  $(".correct-answer").text(correct);
}

function showResults() {
  $(".quiz").hide();
  $(".summary").show();
  $(".summary p").text(
    `Congrats you scored ${score} out of ${questions.length} correct!`
  );
}

function restartQuiz(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  score = 0;
  currentQuestion = 0;
  $(".quiz").show();
  $(".summary").hide();
  showQuestion(currentQuestion);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="start"><a>START</a></div> <!-- add back this button -->
<div class="quiz">
  <h2>Question</h2>
  <div class="answerChoices"></div>
  <form name="radioAnswers">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0"><label id="label0" for=""></label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0"><label id="label1" for=""></label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0"><label id="label3" for=""></label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0"><label id="label4" for=""></label><br>
  </form>
</div>
```